# In IntelliJ Idea, how do you stay in same tab group when stepping into a method in a different class

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ Idea, I often have two tab groups open (I split the screen either vertically or horizontally), A and B.  I often do this, for example, to write a new unit tests in tab A, and use tab B to see what the method being tested does (for mocks, etc).  So while in the class to be tested, I execute Split Right to open the class to test in tab group B, while several tabs are already open in tab group A, including the unit test class.

In tab group B, while in a file/class/tab, I step into a method in a different class.  Sometimes this opens a new tab in tab group B, and sometimes this pops over to tab group A.  I find this very disorienting when stepping into a method switches tab groups, and hides the unit test I am writing.  Is it possible to make stepping into a different class always open the class in the same tab group (even if it is already open in a different tab group?)

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable `Settings/Preferences | Advanced Settings | Editor Tabs | When navigating to a file, prefer selecting existing tab in inactive split pane`:

[image]

Comment: Did the trick for me, thanks.